# Predicted Probabilities with Predict.Plot

Tags: r

I'm running the following logistic regression model in R and one of the important predictors  is `our_bid`, which is a numeric and continuous variable that ranges from 0.30 to 0.80. When I attempt to draw the probability curve for the model using the effects package, I was expecting that I could predict the response variable based on `our_bid` from 0.00 to 2.00. Even though those values aren't present in my data set, I thought I could use the model to predict on values outside the values currently that are in `our_bid`.

```
mod1 = glm(factor(won_ping) ~ our_bid +
  age_of_oldest_driver2 + 
  credit_type2 + 
  coverage_type2 +
  home_owner2 +
  state2 +
  currently_insured2 +
  hour_of_day4 +
  vehicle_driver_score,
  data=dat, family=binomial(link="logit"))

Predict.Plot(mod1, pred.var = "our_bid", our_bid = 250, age_of_oldest_driver2 = "22 to 25",      
             credit_type2 = "FAIR", coverage_type2 = "BASIC", home_owner2 = "1",      
             state2 = "top", currently_insured2 = "1", hour_of_day4 = "1pm to 7pm",      
             vehicle_driver_score = "0", plot.args = "list(xlim=c(0,100))", type = "response")
```

This results in the following plot, which doesn't give all the predicted values from 0 to 1.00. I'm not sure why I'm not able to use the statistical model to predict outside the bounds of the values in that variable (`our_bid`).

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I'm fully understanding your plot here; is our_bid on the x-axis? And why does it range from 0 to 100? Also, do you have example data?

Comment: @ATMathew, I don't see where you are making use of the `effects` package in your code. Would you mind pointing it out?

Comment: It ranged from 0 to 1 because i specified = plot.args = "list(xlim=c(0,100))"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any need for the `rms` package above and the `Predict.Plot` function is not in `rms` or any of the standard packages.

If you mean the `Predict.Plot` function from the `TeachingDemos` package then specifying `xlim` in the `plot.args` section only sets the width of the window and does nothing with the predictions.  If you read the details section of the help page for `Predict.Plot` you will see that you need to give it 2 values for the prediction variable if you want to specify the range that it predicts from (otherwise it just uses the range of the data used to fit the model).  So it looks like you want `our_bid=c(0,100)` or something like that.  If you provide some data in a reproducible format then we can test and give better advice.